# set data as tkinter background?

Tags: python, tkinter

so i found this code:

```
import Image,ImageDraw
import cStringIO
from random import randint as rint

def randgradient():
    img = Image.new("RGB", (300,300), "#FFFFFF")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    r,g,b = rint(0,255), rint(0,255), rint(0,255)
    dr = (rint(0,255) - r)/300.
    dg = (rint(0,255) - g)/300.
    db = (rint(0,255) - b)/300.
    for i in range(300):
        r,g,b = r+dr, g+dg, b+db
        draw.line((i,0,i,300), fill=(int(r),int(g),int(b)))

    f = cStringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(f, "PNG")

    print "Content-type: image/png\n"
    f.seek(0)
    print f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    randgradient()
```

this code has a picture in the memory and im trying to make it a tkinter background with posibly this bit of code:

```
from Tkinter import *
Admin=Tk()
image1 = PhotoImage(file="f.png")
w = image1.width()
h = image1.height()
Admin.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
panel1 = Label(Admin, image=image1)
panel1.pack()
Admin.mainloop
```

it doesn't really matter how i do it but the way just above does not work so how would i go about it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you asking? Is your code throwing an error? Does it run but not hve the expected result? Something else?

Comment: There is a png picture in the memory because of cStringIO and im trying to make that picture in the data the tkinter window background.

Comment: I understand, but you aren't asking a question in your question. Are you asking us to write your code for you? Do you need help with the logic, help with the coding, or help with an error message?

Comment: No, im asking if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an image to a Tk image using PIL's [ImageTk](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) module. See the [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) class examples.